# Result from "aggregate with unwind" is different from the "find with count"?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here is a few documents from my collections:

```
{"make":"Lenovo", "model":"Thinkpad T430"},
{"make":"Lenovo", "model":"Thinkpad T430", "problems":["Battery"]},
{"make":"Lenovo", "model":"Thinkpad T430", "problems":["Battery","Brakes"]}
```

As you can see some documents have **no problems**, some have only **one problem** and some have **few problems** in a list.

**I want to calculate how many reviews have a specific "problem" (like "Battery") in problems list.**

I have tried to use the following aggregate command:

```
{ $match : { model : "Thinkpad T430"} },
{ $unwind : "$problems" },
{ $group: {
        _id: '$problems',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
}}
```

And for battery problem the count was 382. I also decided to double check this result with `find()` and `count()`:

```
db.reviews.find({model:"Thinkpad T430",problems:"Battery"}).count()
```

Result was 362.

**Why do I have this difference? And what is the right way to calculate it?**

Comment: @JohnnyHK no, i just didn't add it to the question. I have $match on the model.

Comment: @JohnnyHK yes, it was an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have documents in the collection where `problems` contains more than one `"Battery"` string in the array.

When using `$unwind`, these will each result in their own doc, so the subsequent `$group` operation will count them separately.